# Getting the error in VDI, after deployment

Tags: c#, rpa, uipath-studio, uipath-robot, uipath-orchestrator

Problem with Uipath BOT after deployment.

Tried removing the Newton JSON and Intelligent OCR Packages if they were installed

Its a Package and cannot show the Code for Security Reasons

We have made an solution using UiPath Core Framework which is running successfully on the local machine that is on developer machine once that code is extracted as a package and when have deployed the Package on VDI and when try to execute that package getting the below mentioned error.

[image: Error Screenshot in VDI]

[image: Error Message from Orchestrator]

Comment: Do you have the same .NET framework (same version) on both machines? And are all packages installed (again, same version) within UiPath Studio in the VDI?

Comment: The issue was with Netwon Json 8.0.3, when up graded to version 11.0.0 it worked fine